# How to open a file using a string variable in path name in batch file

Tags: file, sorting, text, batch-file, path

I have a text file, call it `path.txt` in `C:\path.txt` and it will only have one line of text at a time. That line of text will be a file path, call it `C:\projects\test.txt`.

What's the best way to first read the text from `C:\path.txt` and then second use the sort command in a batch file to alphabetize the file whose path is defined by the text string in `path.txt` ?

Lastly, I want to erase the line of text from that `C:\path.txt` file.

Please let me know if this is too vague or needs a better explanation and thanks in advance.

The batch file I have now reads:

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (C:\DONOTMODIFY.txt) DO @ECHO %%i`

`set "filename=%%i"`

`SORT filename /O filename`

Answer (score 2):

Why the artificial limitation of only one line? Anyway yes this is simple enough. Anyway this will process any number of lines in target.txt. Code off my head so test before real use.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (target.txt) do (
    sort %%i /o %%i
)
echo. > target.txt
```

**EDIT**:

Instead of `echo. > target.txt` you could use `copy /y nul target.txt > nul` that actually creates a totally empty file unlike echo. that makes a blank line.

**PS:** a tip for future questions: Show that you actually tried something. This is not a do my program for you site.

Comment: Thanks that's the key I needed, and thanks for the tip I should have also posted the contents of my batch file. As for the one line limitation it makes a previous step simpler in this design flow and with only one line I thought the for loop may not be neccessary. Originally I had:

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (C:\DONOTMODIFY.txt) DO @ECHO %%i
set "filename=%%i"              

sort filename /o filename

Comment: Well yes but reading files in batch is basically the job of either **for /f**. You could do it like this instead but for is better: **set /p test= < target.txt** followed by **sort %test% /o %test%** But the for loop has the advantage of being able to process many items OR take one line form the file and leave the rest for later processing. So the artificial limitation of one line is redundant. It can still process one line at a time.